# Node.js call function if button clicked

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, raspberry-pi

I have a function in my index.ejs which will be executed if you click on an image.

```
img.onclick = function() {playVideo();}
```

A Video will play, which works fine.

But now I want to get a "notification" in node.js that the function was called / image was clicked. I don't want to send back data or get a var. I just want a function which will be executed in node.js.

I work with node.js and express.js on a raspberry pi.

Look for further infos in the comments.

Comment: Could you please share some more details

Comment: I don't know what other infos you would need or is needed. Could you help?

Comment: where should notification should be shown. Is it web notification.

Comment: I just want to call a function in node.js so for example that it's printing something in the console.

Comment: In that case inside playVideo() you can write a console statement

Comment: Ok maybe I explained it wrong. The console was just an example. I would like to call a function which transmits data over tcp (which works). but I dont know how to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to call the function via a dummy post request.The video will continue playing and the the function will start running in the server

In server

```
   router.post("/call",(req,res,next)=>{<call your function here>});
```

Hope it helps
cheers

Comment: This seems right, but could you explain it a little more. For example I assume that "router" is in my application "app" and how do I call a post in js and whats that next?

Comment: next passes control to next similar route, u will need to call the route from the ejs file

Comment: wrapping a form around the on click button should work

Answer (score 0):

Pass function as a parameter

Example : Create a following method

```
OnSuccess(){
console.log('Event Happened Successfully');
}

img.onclick = function(OnSuccess) {playVideo(OnSuccess);}
```

// In your play video method

```
playvideo(OnSuccess){
//Your play video code
OnSuccess(); // this will call OnSuccess method in line 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to send an ajax request from your UI to the back end to inform it that something happened (button clicked, video loaded, ....).
In ejs you can not pass node js function like this for example:

```
<%=updateButtonClicked();%>
```

Comment: Could you explain it a little more please.